# How to fetch the email body in go ( with imap )?

Tags: go

How to fetch the email body in go ( with imap ) ?. So far I could find the [headers](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#MessageInfo) but there is no indication where to look for the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a FETCH command for the `BODY[]` or `BODY.PEEK[]` attributes.

For more information, see the [IMAP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

Comment: I'm using UIDFetch[1] . Shouldn't that do the trick ?  [1] https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#Client.UIDFetch

Comment: @hey: Yes, but you need to tell it to fetch the attribute.

Comment: how do I tell it what UID to fetch ? My plan would be to loop through all the emails  c.UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER") and then fetch each message using c.UIDFetch(set, "BODY[]") . However I can't figure it out how to set the UID I want to fetch.

Comment: @hey: Use the `seq` parameter.

Comment: Can you show some sample code to fetch the `BODY[]` or `BODY.PEAK[]` attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get the body text. Here is the code:

```
c.Select("INBOX", true)
//fmt.Print("\nMailbox status:\n", c.Mailbox)

// Fetch the headers of the 10 most recent messages
set, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("4:*")
//if c.Mailbox.Messages >= 10 {
//  set.AddRange(c.Mailbox.Messages-9, c.Mailbox.Messages)
//} else {
//  set.Add("1:*")
//}
cmd, _ = c.UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER", "RFC822.TEXT")

// Process responses while the command is running
fmt.Println("\nMost recent messages:")
for cmd.InProgress() {
    // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
    c.Recv(-1)

    // Process command data
    for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
        header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])
        uid := imap.AsNumber((rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
        body := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.TEXT"])
        if msg, _ := mail.ReadMessage(bytes.NewReader(header)); msg != nil {
            fmt.Println("|--", msg.Header.Get("Subject"))
            fmt.Println("UID: ", uid)

            fmt.Println(string(body))
        }
    }
    cmd.Data = nil
    c.Data = nil
}
```

Comment: What package is this from?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just checked my source code. It was `code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble.
I found this example command for use "Fetch" and "Uid".

```
$ UID FETCH uid (body[text])
```

and my C# code example

```
string fileBody = ReceiveResponse($"$ UID FETCH {uidList[i]} (body[text])\r\n");
```